# Assistance with Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been reading other solutions to this question but all the fixes have not worked for me. I have formatted the `date$Date` column to be `as.Date` so I don't understand why I'm still getting this error.

I have the data frame called `data` which contains the total debit amounts for each month. The head of the data looks like this:

```
> head(data)
        Date Debit Amount
1 2017-04-01     17611.82
2 2017-05-01     21073.09
3 2017-06-01     18672.41
4 2017-07-01     18521.02
5 2017-08-01     21695.86
6 2017-09-01     17526.62
```

I simply gave them all to be the first as I read that there needs to be a day to then format as `Date` so I did that. I then create a time series object as:

```
data_ts = ts(data$`Debit Amount`, frequency = 12, start = c(2017, 4))
```

Next I then use `window` in the `forecast` library to split the time series. `smpl1` will be used to forecast and `smpl2` will be to plot the data for the forecasted months:

```
smpl1 = window(datatimeseries, start = c(2017, 4), end = c(2019, 3))
smpl2 = window(datatimeseries, start = c(2019, 4))
```

I have been following a time series analysis in R web page that uses the `HoltsWinters` simple exponential smoothing. Then I use `forecast`, setting the frequency to be monthly (`h = 12`). The code I have is:

```
hw = HoltWinters(smpl1,
                 gamma = FALSE,
                 l.start = 17612, # Initial value
                 b.start = 3461)  # Second - initial
fc = forecast(hw, h = 12)
```

Finaly, I want to plot this using `ggplot2` and found that `ggfortify` can take time series. I also want to have the data `smpl2` plotted as well and found use of `autolayer` to do this. So I have the following:

```
autoplot(fc) +
  autolayer(smpl2, series = "Data") +
  autolayer(fc$mean, series = "Forecasts")
```

This then gives me the error:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

---

One fix that I tried was adding a `geom_rect` to format the x-axis but this too gives me the same error:

```
autoplot(fc) +
  autolayer(smpl2, series = "Data") +
  autolayer(fc$mean, series = "Forecasts") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("2017-04-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                xmax = as.Date("2020-12-01",  "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

I just don't understand this error at all because I used `window` on a time series object and before that the `data$Date` column was formatted using `as.Date`, checked using:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   45 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date        : Date, format: "2017-04-01" "2017-05-01" "2017-06-01" "2017-07-01" ...
 $ Debit Amount: num  17612 21073 18672 18521 21696 ...
```

---

Any help on this would be very much appriciated!

Thanks for reading.

P.S. I will place the full code block here:

```
data_ts = ts(data$`Debit Amount`, frequency = 12, start = c(2017, 4))
smpl1 = window(datatimeseries, start = c(2017, 4), end = c(2019, 3))
smpl2 = window(datatimeseries, start = c(2019, 4))

hw = HoltWinters(smpl1,
                 gamma = FALSE,
                 l.start = 17612, # Initial value
                 b.start = 3461)  # Second - initial
fc = forecast(hw, h = 12)

autoplot(fc) +
  autolayer(smpl2, series = "Data") +
  autolayer(fc$mean, series = "Forecasts") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("2017-04-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                xmax = as.Date("2020-12-01",  "%Y-%m-%d")))
```